# Problem with navigation link: Failed prop type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am making a e-commerce page. The link were functioning ok. When I edited my navbar, one of the options changes the web address I have in my code. I made in one of the option a cart icon with a dropdown where I it appears the picture of the product I have chosen and a button that says "go to check in", but when I click directly the icon, the page turned white. The error that appears in the browser is :

```
arning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CSSTransition`.
    at CSSTransition (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:49009:35)
    at DropdownMenu (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:2154:88)
    at li
    at NavItem (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:2129:76)
    at div
    at ul
    at nav
    at Navbar (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:2113:25)
    at Header (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:1972:64)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:187:62)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:48075:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/golden-shoe/static/js/bundle.js:47555:5)
printWarning @ bundle.js:50159
```

I changed "CSSTransition", I took it from the code, but nothing. It appears the dropdown option but it not render to the page I want.
SO this is my NAV.jsx:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { CounterContext, CartContext } from "../../context/AppContext";
import Dropdown from "../dropdown/Dropdown";
import Button from "../button/Button";
import "./Nav.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef,useContext } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowBarDown } from "../../assets/arrow-bar-down.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Cart } from "../../assets/cart3.svg";
import { ReactComponent as HouseDoor } from "../../assets/house-door.svg";

function Header() {
let count = useContext(CounterContext);
let [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartContext);

  return (

    <Navbar>
        <div className="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow ">
             <Link to="/">
               <img
                 className="logo ml-3"
                 src="./images/g-shoe-new-logo.jpg"
                 alt="logo"
               />
            </Link>  
            <NavItem icon={<ArrowBarDown />} ><Link to="/products">
               <div className="nav-item">
                 <p>Products</p>
               </div>
             </Link></NavItem>
            <NavItem icon={<HouseDoor />}><Link to="/">
               <div className="nav-item active">
                 <p>Home</p>
               </div>
          </Link></NavItem>
            <NavItem icon={<Cart />}>
        <DropdownMenu>
        </DropdownMenu>
        <div className="dropdown-item bbtn-droopdown">
                <div className="moreProd">
                  <Link to="/checkout">
                    <Button value="Go To CheckOut" />
                  </Link>
                </div>  
                </div>
      </NavItem>
      </div>
    </Navbar>
  )


function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">{props.children}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

function NavItem(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a href="#" className="icon-button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {props.icon}
      </a>

      {open && props.children}
    </li>
  );
}

function DropdownMenu() {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState("main");
  const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState(null);
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuHeight(dropdownRef.current?.firstChild.offsetHeight);
  }, []);

  function calcHeight(el) {
     const height = el.offsetHeight;
    setMenuHeight(height);
  }
  function DropdownItem(props) {
    return (
      <a
        href="#"
        className="menu-item"
        onClick={() => props.goToMenu && setActiveMenu(props.goToMenu)}
      >
        <span className="icon-button">{props.leftIcon}</span>
        {props.children}
        <span className="icon-right">{props.rightIcon}</span>
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="dropdown" style={{ height: menuHeight }} ref={dropdownRef}>
      <CSSTransition
        in={activeMenu === "main"}
        timeout={500}
        classNames="menu-primary"
        unmountOnExit
        onEnter={calcHeight}
      >
        <div className="menu">
          <DropdownItem>Go to checkout</DropdownItem>
          <div className="dropdown">
         <CSSTransition
         in={activeMenu === "main"}
        timeout={500}
     classNames="menu-primary"
    unmountOnExit
     onEnter={calcHeight}
      >
        <div className="cart">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-cart2"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M0 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 2H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 4H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1.5 6A.5.5 0 0 1 13 11H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485-.379L1.61 3H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.14 5l1.25 5h8.22l1.25-5H3.14zM5 13a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zm9-1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0z" />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div className="counter">
                <p className="count">{count[0]}</p>
              </div>
        
            <div
              className="dropdown-menu mt-4"
              aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
            >
              <div className="items">
                {cart.length ? (
                  cart.map((item) => {
                    return <Dropdown key={item.id} item={item} />;
                  })
                ) : (
                  <p>Your cart is empty</p>
                )}
              </div>
              </div>

              
      </CSSTransition> 
      </div>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
</div>
  )        
}
}
export default Header;
```

This is Button.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './button.css'

const Button = ({value, floatRight}) => {
    return (
        <div className="button-container">
            <button className={floatRight ? "float-right btn" : 'btn'}>{value}</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

This is Dropdown.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Dropdown = ({ item }) => {
    const { name, imageUrl, price, quantity } = item;
    return (
        <div className="dropdown-item">
            <div className="image">
                <img src={imageUrl} alt='shoes'/>
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <span className='name'>{name}</span>
                <span className='price'>{quantity} X ${price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: are you sure is it the right action to embed CSSTransition inside itself? I am not that expert but I think this may be the problem

Comment: Is the first  time I tried this method. Without the css transition the code work fine but I have to put the css transition apart

Comment: I think you can't use a component as a children to itself

Comment: Yeah , it was that. I mess up with CSS transition. Thanks!

Comment: Can I add it as an answer and you tag it as the right answer?